# Adding comments to a POM.xml file through Java

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I am using `org.apache.maven.model.io.xpp3.MavenXpp3Reader` and `org.apache.maven.model.io.xpp3.MavenXpp3Writer` to perform read and write operations on a POM. I would like to add comments as well. I do not want to process the entire String again and write my logic to insert comments. Is there some other way to insert comments and comment out already present tags?

Answer (score 20):

I know this is old but in case anyone else is looking...
Comments in any xml file, including the POM in a Maven project are signified with with an exclamation tag

```
<!--my comment-->
```

Or an example block commented out

```
  <!--
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.group</groupId>
      <artifactId>anId</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  -->
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.  The question is not how to add comments in a POM file but rather how to have the MavenXpp3Reader and MavenXpp3Writer maintain comments.

Comment: @mario a few years late here, but obviously people needed it.  Function should precede form in most engineering disciplines.  Or format, in this case.  :)